# Splitting MFC from business logic

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to add basic unit testing in an old MFC applications. The goal is to eventually clean out MFC, but until then I wish to at least split the business logic from the MFC code to its own library.

My question is how I best can do this? I want to make as few changes as possible with the sole purpose of getting the business logic free from MFC so I can test it.

I realize that this is only the first step to get the code testable, I have read Working Effectively with Legacy Code.

Comment: "I want to make as few changes as possible with the sole purpose of getting the business logic free from MFC so I can test it."  These are diametrically opposed.  Better: make all the changes you need to make the business logic what it needs to be (e.g. it passes a full set of tests).  Copy/refactor the business logic out of your MFC objects into a new project and new classes that do NOT utilize MFC.  Hopefully that is in CDocument derived classes, and possibly CDialog derived classes or stand-alone classes.  If it's in CView derived classes, it will be a little harder, but still do-able.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know anything about MFC. Are CDocument/CDialog supposed to be in the business logic?

Comment: I don't understand the question then.  Do you WANT to PROPERLY use MFC for Business Logic, or ELIMINATE THE DEPENDENCY of MFC in your Business Logic?  Both are valid goals, but very different.

Comment: 1st I want to make it testable with smallest possible changes. Then I want to remove dependency to MFC.

Comment: If it wasn't designed to be unit-tested (which most MFC applications are not), you are better off using a Window's UI test suite to develop tests with, since your first desire is to test it with "smallest possible changes".  I still recommend what I said in my original comment, but I don't know the background for the MFC based testability requirement (if it is, then it is, so no need to justify it to yours truly).